# CSS Width is not as shown in the console

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am extending a project which uses Twitter Bootstrap. I set the width of my input textbox to be 260px. The css width property is not crossed over in Chrome inspector and is correctly shown 260px, but its actual width is 270px. When I change the width in my stylesheet to 270px, its real width becomes 280px and so on. What can possibly be the causes?

Comment: are you sure there´s no padding affecting the textbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have padding on your input, set it to `0px`.

Comment: yes, you are right. The width declared in the stylesheet doesnt include padding and border. Is there any way to set the width of the input textbox, including its padding and border in css?

Comment: total width of an element is width + padding + border + margin, so you have to calculate the width minus those attributes. For example if the space for the element is 250px and you have 10px padding and 1px border on both sides then the width would be 250 - 10 - 2 = 238.

Comment: Or use `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: @Bojangles: can box-sizing be set to be "border box" on an input control? I tried in Chrome and it says invalid property, the only allowed value is "initial".

Comment: Using `-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;` should work on inputs - http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 1):

check from the  `metrics` view of the chrome inspector. It'll show the `padding` and the `width` being applied to your input.

set `padding:0` if neccessary